# How to apply logarithmic scale to a Google Materials bar chart's axes

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Here's a similar question with no answer:

[Logarithmic scale in material google line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469596/logarithmic-scale-in-material-google-line-chart)

Here's a working JSFiddle of a materials bar chart:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

When editing the JSFiddle I tried:

```
hAxis: {logScale: true}
```

and

```
hAxis: {scaleType: 'log'}
```

But neither of these change the x axis scale to a log type.

google.visualization.BarChart seems to have this ability but google.charts.Bar does not. Is there any documentation on why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several options which simply don't work with *Material* charts

including --> `{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.logScale`

see this issue for the entire list...

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

*Material* chart --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

vs.

*Core* chart --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

or

*Core* chart --> `google.visualization.BarChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`