# Google charts, i cannot use variables inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a query that get from SQL a list of names and theirs fields (OnTime & Delayed). If i use an echo $datosGrafico in php, it shows the below:

```
['Agustin', 17, 1 ],
['Andrea', 79, 0 ],
['Carla', 17, 0 ],
['Cecilia', 6, 0 ],
['Denise', 0, 0 ],
['Diego', 3, 0 ],
['Ezequiel', 0, 0 ],
['German', 0, 0 ],
```

That part is fine. the problem appear once i try to put that variable in the google chart javascript. The script just stop working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["bar"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
    function drawStuff() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'],
        //(The variable $datosGrafico SHOULD GO HERE and avoid to insert every name mannualy)

        ['Agustin', 17, 1],
        ['Lucas', 6, 2], 
        ]);

        var options = {
        width: 425,
        height: 450,
        chart: {
            title: 'Spread of SLAs by Analist',
            subtitle: 'Amount of Tickets'
        },
        bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        }
        ;

        var chart = new 
google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 300px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `<?php echo $datosGrafico; ?>` doesn't work? And you're missing a comma , at the end of the last line.

Comment: Does not working. Also, i've fixed the missing comma. ty.

Comment: @Ramiro, a comma on this place is wrong.

Comment: will you please share the php that builds `$datosGrafico`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution based on comments here! Thanks!

The php PDO query, return the variable:

```
$datosGrafico
```

I added some lines to save that variable result in a php file

```
$fichero = 'tpl\include\test.php';
$actual = $datosGrafico;
file_put_contents($fichero, $actual);
```

and then, i've just added the php code to read that file:

```
dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            var newData = <?php include ('tpl\include\test.php')?>
            var numRows = newData.length;
            var numCols = newData[0].length;

            // in this case the first column is of type 'string'.
            dataTable.addColumn('string', newData[0][0]);

            // all other columns are of type 'number'.
            for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
            dataTable.addColumn('number', newData[0][i]);           

            // now add the rows.
            for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
                dataTable.addRow(newData[i]);
```

Hope this help you in the future!

Comment: This solution is not for your question. Apart from this I do not understand why did you changed accepted answer from my to yours?! You can see on **[your reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10039557/ramiro?tab=reputation&sort=time)** if you accept an answer from somebody you get 2 points, and if you accept an answer from you then you get 0 points.

Comment: Your answer works properly but unfortunatelly as i asked, the var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        ['Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'],
        ['Agustin', 17, 1 ],
        ['Andrea', 79, 0 ],
        ['Carla', 17, 0 ],
        ['Cecilia', 6, 0 ],
        ['Denise', 0, 0 ],
        ['Diego', 3, 0 ],
        ['Ezequiel', 0, 0 ],
        ['German', 0, 0 ]
    ]); need to be a variable because are created on real time with dinamic data (throught php query on SQL server). I'm not here because of points, im here to solve issues.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. This works:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["bar"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
function drawStuff()
{
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        ['Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'],
        ['Agustin', 17, 1 ],
        ['Andrea', 79, 0 ],
        ['Carla', 17, 0 ],
        ['Cecilia', 6, 0 ],
        ['Denise', 0, 0 ],
        ['Diego', 3, 0 ],
        ['Ezequiel', 0, 0 ],
        ['German', 0, 0 ]
    ]);

    var options =
    {
        width: 425,
        height: 450,
        chart:
        {
            title: 'Spread of SLAs by Analist',
            subtitle: 'Amount of Tickets'
        },
        bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    }
    ;

    var chart = new 
    google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 300px; height: 450px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it does not help at all, becase the really problem is that all the lines inside the 
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(.....) need to be a variable that is created by a query with PHP.

Comment: @Ramiro, how do you send your data with PHP? I have to see your PHP code.

Comment: That piece of code is not important in this case. The result is just like i mention. you can check below the solution i've found. Thanks for your help.